# How does a transaction is "resolved" from a SignedTransaction to a LedgerTransaction?

Tags: corda

I found this in the Corda document:
"However, the SignedTransaction holds its inputs as StateRef instances, and its attachments as SecureHash instances, which do not provide enough information to properly validate the transaction’s contents. We first need to **resolve** the StateRef and SecureHash instances into actual ContractState and Attachment instances, which we can then inspect.

We achieve this by using the ServiceHub to **convert** the SignedTransaction into a LedgerTransaction."

What does "resolve" really mean? It is an abstract notion for me, because Hashing is a one way function. 
How does the ServiceHub work to convert a SignedTransaction to a LedgerTransaction?

Answer (score 0):

`SignedTransaction` consists of both the Signature and the Data. The data is in form of `WireTransaciton` (the TxBuilder is converted to a Wire Tx, which is pretty light and contains `stateref` for all inputs & references, It's light as this will be sent over the wire).

Now, once you have the SignedTx, you send it over the wire via Artemis to the counterparty. 
Since we are sending `stateRef` It needs to be resolved into `StateAndRef`so that the counterparty can see the reference data also the counterparty can verify that transaction's integrity by resolving and checking the dependencies.

This is done with the help of `SendTransactionFlow` and `ReceiveTransactionFlow`. All the dependencies are resolved here eg. the attachments, transactions, parameters are requested from the counterparty and recorded. now it can easily be converted to the ledger Tx i.e. `StateRef` into `StateAndRef`, secureHash into `networkparameters` etc.